# Regex findall on a function definition. Want to match args but not function

Tags: python, regex, wildcard, regex-lookarounds, findall

I have a list of strings that look like

```
"funcname(arg, another_arg)*20 + second_func(arg1, arg2)"
```

and I want to pull out just the args. I've tried the following:

```
re.findall(r'\w[\w\d_]+(?!\()', string)
```

however this returns

```
['funcnam', 'arg', 'another_arg', '20', 'second_fun', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```

Firstly, I'm a bit confused as to why I am seeing the `'20'`, since I specified the string should start with a word character. Secondly, I'm wondering how I can improve my look-ahead to match what I'm looking for.

I should note that some of the strings don't have functions and look like

```
"value1 + value_two"
```

so I can't simply search inside the parentheses.

Comment: `\w` matches any alphanumeric character and _

Comment: So for the string `"value1 + value_two"`, do you want this to give you `["value1", "value2"]` or `[]`?

Comment: I sure hope you don't care about nested expressions, else you've fallen prey to [Cthulhu](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: I want `["value1", "value2"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> pattern = '[a-zA-Z_]\w*(?![\(\w])'
>>> re.findall(pattern, "funcname(arg, another_arg)*20 + second_func(arg1, arg2)")
['arg', 'another_arg', 'arg1', 'arg2']
>>> re.findall(pattern, "value1 + value_two")
['value1', 'value_two']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that should work better:

```
(?!\w+\()[^\W\d]\w+
```

For example:

```
>>> s = "funcname(arg, another_arg)*20 + second_func(arg1, arg2)"
>>> re.findall(r'(?!\w+\()[^\W\d]\w+', s)
['arg', 'another_arg', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```

`[^\W\d]` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_]`.

This uses the same logic as your regex, but by moving the lookahead to the beginning of the string you prevent a match like `funcnam` from `funcname(...)`.  Here is a similar alternative:

```
[^\W\d]\w+(?![\w(])
```

Comment: Ah very nice. Does that lookahead apply to each character in \w+ then?

Comment: Your original regex didn't work because the lookahead would cause the match to fail if the next character was a `(`, but that just allowed your regex to backtrack one character and return the function name without the last character.  If you move the lookahead to the beginning the match will fail for function names before matching anything, which prevents backtracking.  The other option to prevent the backtracking is to fail if the next character is in `\w` using `\w+(?!\w)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bad solution, but it works for me...:

```
R=r"[a-zA-Z_]\w*(?:s*\()?"  #This captures everything, leaving the left parenthesis on functions
values=filter(lambda x: '(' != x[-1], re.findall(R,s))  #now filter off everything containing a left parenthesis
#Or if you prefer list comprehensions...
values=[ x for x in re.findall(R,s) if x[-1]!='(' ]
```

The other answers will probably be better than this though...The one benefit of this is that it allows you to easily pick out functions after the fact -- they end with '('

Comment: @jamylak  Yes.  I don't know how I changed that when I copied it over.